# download file from url and read later locally

Tags: android

I want to download a file from url to read this file later locally. I have this code to download the file:

```
private void startDownload() {
    String url = "my url";
    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
}
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Actualizando programa..");
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            return mProgressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/myfile.json");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return null;

    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
         Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
         mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }
}
```

I don´t know where it will be save the file with this code and how can I read this file later locally.

Answer (score 1):

To save your file, to your app dir use this:

```
//save to cache
    try {
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(activity.getFilesDir(), "/myfile.json")));
        oos.writeObject(list);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

To retrieve content:

```
   ObjectInputStream dis = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(context.getFilesDir(), "/myfile.json")));
    ArrayList<String> = (ArrayList<String>) dis.readObject();
        dis.close();
```

I hope it helps!